# javascript populate nested object from other nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, hash

I am rather new to JavaScript and I am following different tutorials at the moment. For visualisation of a d3js graph I like to restructure a small dataset so that the `d3.layout.stack()` function can deal with the data.
The original dataset looks as follows. Its an array of objects:

```
var dats = [{ apples: 5, oranges: 10, grapes: 22 },
            { apples: 4, oranges: 12, grapes: 28 },
            { apples: 2, oranges: 19, grapes: 32 },
            { apples: 7, oranges: 23, grapes: 35 },
            { apples: 23, oranges: 17, grapes: 43 }
            ];
```

The target object should look as follows. its an Array of Array of objects:

```
var finaldats = [
            [{ x: 0, y: 5 },
             { x: 1, y: 4 },
             { x: 2, y: 2 },
             { x: 3, y: 7 },
             { x: 4, y: 23 }
            ],
            [{ x: 0, y: 10 },
             { x: 1, y: 12 },
             ...
```

My approach so far:

```
var inner = {}
        inner["x"] ;
        inner["y"] ;

        dats.forEach(function(d,i) {
            inner["x"] = i
            inner["y"] = dats[i].apples;
        });
```

This produces: `Object {x: 4, y: 23}`
Its always the last element of the input array, which is fine, since the object is constantly overwritten in each iteration.
At the moment I fail to push these objects, being created in each iteration into an array.

I thought of something like this, but it does not work:

```
var inner = {}
            inner["x"] ;
            inner["y"] ;
var outer = [];

        dats.forEach(function(d,i) {
            inner["x"] = i
            inner["y"] = dats[i].apples;
            outer.push(inner);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map`:

> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var dats = [{ apples: 5, oranges: 10, grapes: 22},             
        { apples: 4, oranges: 12, grapes: 28}, 
        { apples: 2, oranges: 19, grapes: 32}, 
        { apples: 7, oranges: 23, grapes: 35}, 
        { apples: 23, oranges: 17, grapes: 43}
       ];

var inner = dats.map(function(d, i) {
  return {
    x: i,
    y: d.apples
  }

});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(inner, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

**Edit**:
To get the result for all the Keys you can use below snippet:

```js
var dats = [{ apples: 5, oranges: 10, grapes: 22},             
            { apples: 4, oranges: 12, grapes: 28}, 
            { apples: 2, oranges: 19, grapes: 32}, 
            { apples: 7, oranges: 23, grapes: 35}, 
            { apples: 23, oranges: 17, grapes: 43}
           ];

var inner = dats.map((o) => {
  return Object.keys(o)
}).reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return prev.concat(curr)
}).filter((col, i, array) => {
  return array.indexOf(col) === i
}).map(function(k) {
  return dats.map(function(a, i) {
    return {
      x: i,
      y: a[k]
    };
  });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(inner, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Read more about [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2):

While the other solution features only a part of the solution, here the complete solution with an array for the keys and two nested [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), one for the keys `['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']` and one for the values in the `dats`.

```js
var dats = [{ apples: 5, oranges: 10, grapes: 22 }, { apples: 4, oranges: 12, grapes: 28 }, { apples: 2, oranges: 19, grapes: 32 }, { apples: 7, oranges: 23, grapes: 35 }, { apples: 23, oranges: 17, grapes: 43 }],
    finaldats = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes'].map(function (k) {
        return dats.map(function (a, i) {
            return { x: i, y: a[k] };
        });
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(finaldats, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This is the complete answer. I was going to put something similar until I refreshed the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I do have some experience with Ruby, but JavaScript works a little different here and there.